# Is it possible to build a "filtered tuple" or "filtered parameter pack" from a template parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a situation where I want to call some function on each value in a template parameter pack, and store the result of calling that function in a stack-allocated variable. For instance:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

char const* format_value(double x) { /* ... */ }
std::string format_value(long x) { /* ... */ }

template <typename Sink, typename... Values>
Sink& format(Sink& target, Values... values)
{
    // Does not compile; Not valid C++11
    typedef std::tuple<typename std::result_of<format_value(values)>::type...> tuple_type;
    tuple_type slices(format_value(values)...);
    /* Code that does things with the results. */
}
```

Is it possible to do this sort of filtering, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: What is *being filtered* BTW?

Comment: @Nawaz: In this specific case, maybe "transformed" would be a better word. The function `format_value` serves as a shim between whatever type the user supplies, and a type that provides members `size()` and `data()` containing the results. But I tried to keep the question general rather than discuss the specific formatting bits I've been working on.

Comment: Ohh.. BTW, if the transformed values are of same type (or converted into same type), then you could use array instead of tuple. In this case, `std::string slices[] { format_values(values)... }; ` would work great . The advantage with array is that you don't need templates to iterate it (tuple needs template for iteration). Also, you could use `std::array` if you want, that is a choice!

Comment: @Nawaz: The transformed values aren't always the same type. Here's what I'm working on: https://github.com/BillyONeal/Instalog/blob/5987cdf0fac1afee9b0f4225509ee1d3a869927e/LogCommon/LogSink.hpp . I want to allow `format_value` to return something that doesn't require heap allocation. (Think of this as a lame [fastformat](http://fastformat.sourceforge.net/) updated for C++11)

Comment: I posted an answer after seeing your code at github. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alright. I saw [your code at github](https://github.com/BillyONeal/Instalog/blob/5987cdf0fac1afee9b0f4225509ee1d3a869927e/LogCommon/LogSink.hpp) and hopefully know what you're trying to achieve.

I think you can still avoid the recursive call to `format_buffer()`. Here is the part I'm talking about:

```
template <typename Slice, typename... Slices>
char const* format_buffer(char* ptr, std::size_t length, Slice const& slice, Slices const& ...slices)
{
    std::size_t const size = slice.size();
    std::copy_n(slice.data(), size, ptr);
    return format_buffer(ptr + size, length - size, slices...);
}

template <typename Sink, typename... Slices>
Sink& write_impl(Sink& target, Slices &&...slices)
{
    std::size_t const length = sum_sizes(slices...);
    OptimisticBuffer<256> buff(length);
    char* ptr = buff.GetAs<char>();
    char const* endPtr = format_buffer(ptr, length, slices...);
    target.append(ptr, endPtr - ptr);
    return target;
}
```

Can be replaced with this:

```
struct unpack { template<typename ...T> unpack(T && ...) {} };

template <typename Sink, typename... Slices>
Sink& write_impl(Sink& target, Slices &&...slices)
{
    std::size_t const length = sum_sizes(slices...);
    OptimisticBuffer<256> buff(length);
    char* ptr = buff.GetAs<char>();
    char *origin = ptr;
    unpack { (ptr = std::copy_n(slices.data(), slices.size(), ptr)) ... } ;
    target.append(origin, ptr - origin);
    return target;
}
```

The magic happens at `unpack {}` line. For each `slice` in `slices`, you call `std::copy_n` which returns `ptr+size` (which is then stored in `ptr`) which becomes the input for the next call to `std::copy_n` and so on:

```
 unpack { (ptr = std::copy_n(slices.data(), slices.size(), ptr)) ... } ;
```

expands to this:

```
 unpack 
 { 
     (ptr = std::copy_n(slices0.data(), slices0.size(), ptr)),
     (ptr = std::copy_n(slices1.data(), slices1.size(), ptr)),
     (ptr = std::copy_n(slices2.data(), slices2.size(), ptr)),
      .
      .
     (ptr = std::copy_n(slicesN.data(), slicesN.size(), ptr)),
 };
```

Note that since it uses *list-initialization*, the *order* of evaluation of expressions is guaranteed to be left-to-right, i.e top-to-down in the expanded form!

Since [GCC has bug since 4.7.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253) (which is why currently it doesn't work), you can write this:

```
using unpack = void const*[];

unpack {(ptr=std::copy_n(slicesN.data(),slicesN.size(), ptr))...};`
```

Another improvement would be this: instead of `sum_sizes()`, I would implement `sum` so that instead of this:

```
 std::size_t const length = sum_sizes(slices...);
```

I could write this:

```
 std::size_t const length = sum(slices.size()...);
```

In this way, `sum()` would be more reusable, like:

```
 std::size_t const x = sum(args.get_element_size()...);
 std::size_t const y = sum(sizeof(Ts)...);
```

if you ever need these. Well, in case of `sizeof`, a compile-time `sum<>` would be better — though the point remains same, `sum` is more reusable than `sum_sizes()`.

Comment: If I were to design this library, I would implement `OptimisticBuffer` in such a way that it could be treated as `OutputIterator` so that I don't have to assign the return value of `std::copy_n` to `ptr` ( i.e `ptr = std::copy_n(...)` part), as it looks a bit ugly, but then when you write template and add meta programming stuff, the code is already ugly. But still we should strive for improvement wherever possible.

Comment: Yeah, it probably deserves a wrapper that does that. (That class is used across this codebase in places where an iterator is not feasible (calling into C APIs))

Comment: In testing, this doesn't work, because the order of calls to `copy_n` in the construction of `unpack` are unsequenced when expanded this way. Results in scrambled output, e.g. http://ideone.com/ZGuw6U

Comment: Note that GCC doesn't correctly implement LTR-evaluation for class-types. I'd replace `unpack` with `using unpack = int[];` and do `unpack{ 0, (expr, 0)... };`. See also [my message here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/YkHPCYb-KPQ/WwE4OovzcHIJ).

Comment: @BillyONeal: I forgot to tell you that GCC has bug. Anyway, you could replace `unpack { ...}` with `char* unpack[] { _same_as_before_ };`. This should work!

Comment: @BillyONeal: It is [GCC bug since 4.7.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253).

Comment: @Xeo + Nawaz: Apparently MSVC++ has the same bug, because that's what I tested on that produced the above scrambled output.

Comment: @Nawaz: https://github.com/BillyONeal/Instalog/commit/4ee1f6625c72dee1d4e16b4fca155717552c028f :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `auto` and a function which accepts a parameter pack to generate the requisite tuple. For instance, `std::make_tuple` works just fine:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

char const* format_value(double x) { /* ... */ }
std::string format_value(long x) { /* ... */ }

template <typename Sink, typename... Values>
Sink& format(Sink& target, Values... values)
{
    auto slices = std::make_tuple(format_value(values)...);
    /* Code that does things with the results. */
}
```

Similarly, you may also be able to avoid using tuple altogether by forwarding to another function. For instance:

```
#include <string>

char const* format_value(double x) { /* ... */ }
std::string format_value(long x) { /* ... */ }

template <typename Sink, typename... Results>
void format_impl(Sink& target, Results... results)
{
    /* Code that does things with the results. */
}

template <typename Sink, typename... Values>
Sink& format(Sink& target, Values... values)
{
    format_impl(target, format_value(values)...);
    return sink;
}
```

Comment: @Nawaz: Maybe, maybe not. I spent a bunch of time trying to figure it out, and figured there might be at least one other person for whom it is not straightforward from the get-go. There are those who eat templates for breakfast, lunch, and dinner, but sadly I'm not one of those people.